# Postgres insert all rows with max min values

Tags: postgresql

I want to select all rows from one table and insert them into another with only the max and min values on all rows. Cant figure out how to write this without a group by clause. Its a big table so (update set=? from (select max...)) is to slow

table1:

```
id,values  
1,2  
2,4  
3,1
```

table2:

```
id,max,min  
1,4,1  
2,4,1  
3,4,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another try using **window functions** (SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2978e)
This is the select to get your data.

```
select 
  id, 
  min(values) over () as min, 
  max(values) over () as max 
from Table1
```

To **insert** these values one has to execute this sql

```
insert into table2 (id, min, max)
select 
  id, 
  min(values) over () as min, 
  max(values) over () as max 
from Table1
```

or to **create** table2 from the sql

```
create table table2 as
select 
  id, 
  min(values) over () as min, 
  max(values) over () as max 
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT n1.id,
       n2.mymax,
       n2.mymin
FROM
  (SELECT MIN(values) AS mymin,
          MAX(values) AS mymax
   FROM dbTable) n2,
     dbTable n1;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/861e5/1):